# TokBox (OpenTok) Android SDK Increasing Size

Tags: android, video, sdk, tokbox

I have implemented **Tokbox (OpenTok)** Android SDK to avail Video Feature within the app. But the SDK has many more features like Screen Sharing, Picture in Picture, Custom Audio driver, and because of this the apk size increased to 20 MB and 18 is the TokBox SDK.

I have applied App Bundle but still the size is too much. Is there any proguard rule for toxbox Sdk, so to avail only video or any part of tokbox sdk for implementing Video.

Comment: Hi! I'm facing the same issue. Apparently, openTok team does not want to give good proguard rules: https://github.com/opentok/opentok-android-sdk-samples/issues/178 For now I'm using -keep class com.opentok.** { *; }
-keep class org.webrtc.** { *; } but of course, these rules are too broad...